# Ububtu 18.04 sudo apt-get update is not working

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

I'm getting following errors while running sudo apt-get update command in my system(ubuntu 18.04) and also not able to install any new application:-

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                         
Ign:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease      
Hit:4 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release        
Get:5 http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian jessie InRelease [3,263 B]
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/hal-flash/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Ign:11 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                        
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security InRelease             
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                       
Ign:14 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                    
Err:5 http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian jessie InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB
Hit:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Get:18 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release [11.9 kB]                
Hit:19 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty Release                      
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease               
Get:22 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release.gpg [72 B]               
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease              
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:8 https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.3/repo/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease             
Hit:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Ign:29 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic InRelease                 
Ign:22 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release.gpg                      
Err:21 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                    
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease                       
Get:32 https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian bionic Release [74.5 kB]         
Hit:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates InRelease               
Hit:16 https://downloads.mariadb.com/Tools/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports InRelease             
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease               
Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Err:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Hit:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Err:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Hit:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release                         
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmiller-opensource/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:46 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmiller-opensource/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                
W: GPG error: http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian jessie InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 199369E5404BD5FC7D2FE43BCBCB082A1BB943DB
E: The repository 'http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian jessie InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192
E: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.3/repo/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://downloads.mariadb.com/Tools/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmiller-opensource/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:12
```

Please suggest the steps need to perform to resolve this problem.

These errors while running sudo apt-get update command in my system(ubuntu 18.04) and also not able to install any new application.

Comment: In my case, i got this error when i run this command just after the installation of ubuntu but tried without providing wifi connection to my pc. So, please make sure your internet connection is enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of tons of PPAs that you have added!

Try to remove all those PPAs from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run `sudo apt update` again, then everything should work fine. (If you want `/etc/apt/sources.list` take a look at [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398031) link)

I should mention that adding that much of PPAs is risky and you should try to avoid that! (Unless it's necessary, make sure you are adding a secure ppa.)

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging the resources it is complaining about to see if you are able to get a response.

I have tried http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and can resolve it fine so it maybe firewall or proxy related.